# How to send raw packet on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, sockets

[How Do I Use Raw Socket in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117958/how-do-i-use-raw-socket-in-python)

I see the following code is used to send raw packet.

```
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)
s.bind(("eth1", 0))
...
s.send(dst_addr+src_addr+ethertype+payload+checksum)
```

But when I try it on Mac, I see this. I am not sure what is the appropriate way to send a raw packet on MacOS. Could anybody let me know?

```
NameError: name 'AF_PACKET' is not defined
```

Here is what is shown on help page of macOS. Is any of them appropriate?

```
     |  AF_APPLETALK = <AddressFamily.AF_APPLETALK: 16>
     |
     |  AF_INET = <AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>
     |
     |  AF_INET6 = <AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 30>
     |
     |  AF_IPX = <AddressFamily.AF_IPX: 23>
     |
     |  AF_LINK = <AddressFamily.AF_LINK: 18>
     |
     |  AF_ROUTE = <AddressFamily.AF_ROUTE: 17>
     |
     |  AF_SNA = <AddressFamily.AF_SNA: 11>
     |
     |  AF_SYSTEM = <AddressFamily.AF_SYSTEM: 32>
     |
     |  AF_UNIX = <AddressFamily.AF_UNIX: 1>
     |
     |  AF_UNSPEC = <AddressFamily.AF_UNSPEC: 0>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169298/af-packet-on-osx

Comment: Not a duplicate. This is about python. That one is not.

Answer (score 0):

## Example

```py
import socket
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock:
    packet = create_packet()
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
    sock.sendto(packet, (ip, port))
```

```py
import socket
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.connect(("localhost", 8080))
socket.send("content")
socket.close()
```

Here is an example python file that sends wakeonlan magic packets.

- https://github.com/HuakunShen/wol/blob/master/wol-py/wol.py

Here are some examples from socket documentation

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example

Comment: I don't think this is equivalent. In my example, it is not a TCP/IP packet. Is just an IP packet? (ICMP packet should be sent by that piece of code on Linux.)